# Is there any widget for Amazon AWS Login? LIke FB Button widget

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am creating a DevOps application where users come to our website. They authenticate with AWS using there username and password. Then they can manage their EC2 instances (this is bit simplified - I know it may sound childish). My first instinct was that it can be done with AWS Cognito. But boy I was wrong. So I am basically looking for Javascript widget or any PHP/python API that allows me to authenticate an AWS Account using Username (email) and password.

Tried AWS Cognito
Tried Boto API / PHP SDK but they work off app key / secret

Comment: I would hope no such thing exists; the only valid use case for IAM user/pass credentials is to log directly in to the AWS console.

Comment: You can use cognito hosted GUI to manage the login, then create backend API to consume their ID Token/Authorization Code to grant them temporary credentials and manage EC2. That's about as simple as you can get it.